# Modal pop up wont show up regardless of what i do

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

am currently trying to find a way to open up a modal box based on the rows in the table. however when i run the program and click the edit button, the modal wont show up. Here is a sample code:

Gridview:

```
<asp:Gridview CssClass=" table table-borderless" ID="PO_Form" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="PO_Form_RowCommand">

            <Columns>           

             <asp:ButtonField  Text="Edit" ControlStyle-CssClass="page-link" CommandName="EditForm"/>

             <asp:BoundField DataField="PO_no" HeaderText="PO No." />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="supplier_name" HeaderText="Supplier name" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="flight_no" HeaderText="Flight No." />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="bkg_date" HeaderText="Booking Date" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
         </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
        </asp:Gridview>
    </div>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="editmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <%-- Modal Content --%>

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    Test
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

back code:

```
protected void PO_Form_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.CommandName == "EditForm")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "EditFormModal();", true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Would be useful to include the `EditFormModal()` function in your question. Have you verified that the posted back page includes both the modal markup and the `EditFormModal` function?

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened